# My word tally program only tallies the last word in a text file. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: python

I want to tally up the word freq. from text files. The issue I'm facing is that only the last word is tallied.

```
def main():

    rep = input("Enter a text file: ")
    infield = open(rep, 'r')

    s = infield.read()
    punctuation = [',',';','.',':','!',"'","\""]
    for ch in punctuation:
        s = s.replace(ch,' ')
    s = s.split()
    wordcount = {}
    for word in s:
        if word not in wordcount:
            count_1 = s.count(word)
            wordcount = {word:count_1} 
            #s.append(w:s.count(w))
    print (wordcount)

main()
```

Expected: A tallied word count for words in a text file in a key-value format/ a dictionary.

Actual: {'fun': 2}
Fun is the last word of the text file and indeed comes up only twice.
Also, the indentation that is displayed isn't reflective of what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
wordcount = {word:count_1}
```

You're **overwriting the dictionary** on every loop iteration.

Make it:

```
wordcount[word] = count_1
```

---

Though, to be honest, the much better approach is to **use the standard library's [`collections.Counter` container](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)**.

```py
def main():
    import collections

    rep = input("Enter a text file: ")
    infield = open(rep, 'r')

    s = infield.read()
    punctuation = [',',';','.',':','!',"'","\""]
    for ch in punctuation:
        s = s.replace(ch,' ')
    s = s.split()
    wordcount = collections.Counter(s) # <===
    print (wordcount.most_common())    # <===

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm only allowed to use what we've learned in class thus far. However, I'll remember this alternative for the future!

Answer (score 2):

No point in manually doing something that is already done in the standard library (since Python 2.7):

```
from collections import Counter
import re
rep = input("Enter a text file: ")
infield = open(rep, 'r')
s = infield.read()
s = re.split(r'[ ,;.:!\'"]', s)
wordcount = Counter(s)
del wordcount['']
print (wordcount)
```

There is a difference between `re.split()` and `string.split()`: the former creates empty words when there are several delimiters in a row, the latter doesn't. That's why `del wordcount['']`

Comment: Appreciate the help! Unfortunately, I'm only allowed to use what we've learned thus far in class. Hopefully, that'll extend to counter soon.

Answer (score 1):

You had a couple of issues, but the most pressing one was this bit of code:

```
for word in s:
    if word not in wordcount:
        count_1 = s.count(word)
        wordcount = {word:count_1}
```

You were setting `wordcount` to a single-key dictionary at every new word. This is how I would have written it...

```
def main():
    punctuation = [',',';','.',':','!',"'","\""]
    rep = input("Enter a text file: ")

    with open(rep, 'r') as infield:
        s = infield.read()
        for ch in punctuation:
            s = s.replace(ch, ' ')
        s = s.split()
        wordcount = {}
        for word in s:
            if word not in wordcount.keys():
                wordcount[word] = 1
            else:
                wordcount[word] += 1
    print(wordcount)
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wordcount.update({word: count_1})` instead: `wordcount = {word:count_1}`.

Full example:

```
# coding: utf-8

PUNCTUATION = [',', ';', '.', ':', '!', "'", "\""]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordcount = {}
    rep = input("Enter a text file: ")
    infield = open(rep, 'r')
    s = infield.read()
    for ch in PUNCTUATION:
        s = s.replace(ch, ' ')
    s = s.split()

    for word in s:
        if word not in wordcount:
            count_1 = s.count(word)
            wordcount.update({word: count_1})

    print(wordcount)
```

Comment: I don't really see the need for `if __name__ == '__main__':` if all that's in the script otherwise is a single line that defines a variable.

Comment: @JordanSinger hm, yep. sorry, its my habit.

Comment: It's a good habit to be in if you're working on projects where you have scripts that define functions which are being referenced elsewhere in the project. Otherwise, it's pretty much just clutter ;)

Comment: I appreciate the help!